# HTML and CSS- Vertical scroll bar not shrinking/resizing in window of fixed height/width containing content

Tags: html, css, web, scroll

So I am trying to make a website and have a popup window/box that appears after clicking something. This popup window contains text/content, let's name it "Locations," as per my website's design. This Locations Popup box has a fixed height and width, and consequently, there is a vertical scroll bar I've created to scroll down and read the text. I would like to add more content to this popup but unfortunately, the text is being cutoff, and the scroll does not continue scrolling down. TO be more specific, how can I add in or change something such that the vertical scroll will re-size/shrink itself so as to accommodate for the extra text I am adding? Currently, the text is just cutoff in the window, and I cannot scroll down to read it. In correct applications of vertical scroll bar integration, by my understanding, the scroll bar should re-size itself so that all the text until the very end can be scrolled and read. Please let me know if other code snippets are necessary for this. Below is the CSS for it:

```
/* Pop Up */
#popupAbout, #popupLocations, #popupContact, #popupBlog {
    height: 600px;
    width: 900px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    border: 2px solid #cecece;
    z-index: 15;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And to make it a bit easier in providing me assistance with this, I've added the JS for it as well:

```
//Locations Page Pop Up
            var popupLocationsStatus = 0;

            function loadPopupLocations(){
                if(popupLocationsStatus==0){
                    $("#popupLocations").fadeIn("slow");
                    popupLocationsStatus = 1;
                }
            }

            function disablePopupLocations(){
                if(popupLocationsStatus==1){
                    $("#popupLocations").fadeOut("slow");
                    popupLocationsStatus = 0;
                }
            }

            function centerPopupLocations(){
                var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
                var popupLocationsHeight = $("#popupLocations").height();
                var popupLocationsWidth = $("#popupLocations").width();
                $("#popupLocations").css({
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "top": windowHeight/2-popupLocationsHeight/2,
                    "left": windowWidth/2-popupLocationsWidth/2
                });
            }


            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#popupLocations").fadeOut();
                popupLocationsStatus = 0;
                $("#Locations").click(function(){
                $("#popupLocations").css({
                    "visibility": "visible" });
                    disablePopupAbout();
                    disablePopupContact();                  
                    centerPopupLocations();
                    loadPopupLocations();
                });
                $("#popupLocationsClose").click(function(){
                    disablePopupLocations();
                });
            });
            $(function()
            {
                $('#popupLocations').jScrollPane();
                $('.popupLocations').jScrollPane(
                    {
                        showArrows: true,
                        horizontalGutter: 10
                    }
                );
            });
```

Comment: could you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle is where we see the code